# Specifying Encrypted password in JDBC OCI Connection String

Tags: java, database, encryption, jdbc, oracle-call-interface

I've a standalone application that we use to connect to the Oracle database. In the past, we used JDBC to connect to it, but now due to various reasons we've switched towards using OCI thick client. But we still specifiy the connection url. The only problem I'm running to is that, I'm no longer able to user encrypted password, or I don't know how to use it yet.

In the past for jdbc,we used.

jdbc:oracle:thin:**username**/**encryptedpassword**@hostname:port:abc;passwordEncrypted=true

I was wondering if anyone knew of a similar way in which I could use the OCI driver, and use the encrypted password.  It works fine when I use non-encrypted password.